# Should Scheduled Task start a Spring application each time it is executed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot application with a scheduled task. It is divided into two maven projects, lets call them 'lib' and 'app'.

The class whose method is annotated with `@Scheduled` is located in 'lib' project. It does not contain any classes annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, or any classes that start a spring application. Here's what `Scheduled` bean looks like:

```
@Component
public class Refresher {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void refresh() {
        ...
    }
```

The 'lib' project also has a simple `SchedulingConfigurer` implementation that tells Spring to use `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with its Scheduled tasks.

The 'app' project, on the other hand, has a dependency on 'lib' and has a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, and starts it as usual:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"x.y", "x.y.z"})
@EnableScheduling
public class ExampleService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleService.class, args);
    }
}
```

Both maven projects have this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

So, when `ExampleService` starts I see it finds `Refresher` and executes its `refresh` method once every 30 sec alright, but something strange appears in the logs. When Example service starts, it prints:

```
2019-01-11 18:18:27.647  INFO 6428 --- [           main] x.y.z.ExampleService  : Started ExampleService in 32.613 seconds (JVM running for 40.37)
```

This is great, it tells me that main application has started. But then I get the following lines every 30 seconds, every time Refresher gets executed:

```
2019-01-11 18:18:58.596  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@66e31414: startup date [Fri Jan 11 18:18:58 MSK 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-11 18:18:58.637  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c355e31] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
... some logging from the refresh() method
2019-01-11 18:19:01.020  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1262db58: startup date [Fri Jan 11 18:19:01 MSK 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@66e31414
2019-01-11 18:19:01.035  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 3.585 seconds (JVM running for 73.771)
2019-01-11 18:19:01.035  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1262db58: startup date [Fri Jan 11 18:19:01 MSK 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@66e31414
2019-01-11 18:19:01.035  INFO 6428 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@66e31414: startup date [Fri Jan 11 18:18:58 MSK 2019]; root of context hierarchy
```

Notice 'Started application in 3.585 seconds (JVM running for 73.771)'. This happens every 30 seconds. It looks like in order to run the `Scheduled` bean Spring runs a new separate Spring application every time. Why would it do that, and can this be avoided? Can `Scheduled` bean run as part of currently started Spring Boot app?

Comment: What is your `Refresher` doing exactly.

Comment: It is essentially calling local actuator on http://localhost:port/actuator/refresh to make it check for config changes on server (spring cloud config server is used). It then analyses config and that's it.

Comment: Calling that endpoint will restart the context... Hence the fact you see what you see. \

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, thanks. I also found this [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/380) that kinda confirms it. So, to the only way to re-get configuration from server is to periodically refresh actuator, which leads to periodical application re-start. Doesn't sound right to me... would you agree?

Comment: Assuming you are using the `spring-cloud-config` server you can also just call that to get the most recent configuration. The whole point of the `/refresh` is to refresh the `@RefeshScoped` beans which means reconfiguration parts of the application. The only way to do that is to (partially) restart the application.

Comment: You mean manual call via REST? That would be fine, but then configuration properties will not be automatically updated wherever they are autowired, correct?

Comment: No that is where the `/refresh` endpoint comes in.